# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx/subjects/SerializedSubject Error getting when I upgrade from rxJava1.0.3 to rxJava1.3.0

Tags: rx-java

I am trying to upgrade from rxjava1.0.4 to rxJava1.3.0 and getting Below error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx/subjects/SerializedSubject.
Do anyone having idea how to fix it?

Comment: How do you import the RxJava dependency (Maven/ Gradle)? It looks like the SerializedSubject is there at compile time but not in runtime. So this could be a versioning of transitive dependencies.

Comment: Maven: <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

Comment: The OP has also created an [issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5690) with additional information that implies configuration/deployment problems.